# Removing one element from an entire dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I've been working on this thing for hours, still cant figure it out :O

The problem I'm having is this. Lets say I have a dictionary with 4-element tuples as elemets and an integer as key. When an element is removed from the whole dictionary (which belongs to every tuple) making two of the tuples (elements) same, the keys of the two tuples don't add up. Instead, a new element is formed, with the key for that element being one of the previous 2 keys.

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
dict={('A','B','D','C'): 4, ('C','B','A','D'):5, ('D','A','C','B'):3,('D','A','B','C'):1}
```

Now I wanna remove one letter from the entire dictionary.
for example, If I wanna remove 'B'. The following new dictionary is formed, but isn't returned, because two of the elements are the same.

```
 {('A','D','C'): 4, ('C','A','D'):5, ('D','A','C'):3,('D','A','C'):1}
```

Instead of `('D','A','C'):3,('D','A','C'):1` becoming `('D','A','C'):4`, this is what ends up happenening:

`('D','A','C'):3` along with other tuples

So basically, one of the tuples disappears.

This is the method I'm currently using:

```
for next in dict:
new_tuple=()
for i in next:
    if i!='A':
        new_tuple+=(i,)
new_dict[new_tuple]=dict[next]
```

The above code returns new_dict as the following:

```
 {('A','D','C'): 4, ('C','A','D'):5, ('D','A','C'):3}
```

So what can I do, to remove one letter from every tuple in the entire dictionary, and if two of the tuples look the same, they merge and the keys add up?

Comment: Your dictionaries have tuples as keys and integers as values, not "tuples as elemets and an integer as key."

Comment: `next` is a reserved word in Python!

Comment: dictionaries are not so efficient for changing all the keys as you will have to rehash them.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to rebuild your entire dictionary, as each key/value pair is going to be affected. You can use a `defaultdict` to make the merging easier when you encounter now-overlapping keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_dict = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in old_dict.items():
    new_key = tuple(i for i in key if i != 'A')
    new_dict[new_key] += value
```

Because when first looking up `new_key` in `new_dict` it'll be set to `0` by default, all we have to do is add the old value to update `new_dict` for when we first encounter a key. The next time we encounter the key the values are 'merged' by adding them up.

Comment: is there a way to do it without importing anything though?

Comment: And after you build it, you can set `new_dict.default_factory = None` to make it behave like a regular dictionary with respect to `KeyError`s and such.

Comment: @JunaidPatel: Sure, `new_dict = {}`, then instead of `new_dict[new_key] += value` do `new_dict[new_key] = new_dict.get(new_key, 0) + value`.